# Catch problem with await in React 17, jest and testing library

Tags: reactjs, async-await, jestjs, eslint, react-testing-library

I've got a problem in a test:

This is my code:

```js
  test("should render text component", async () => {
        render(<TextComponent />)
        const headings = await screen.findAllByRole("heading")
        expect(headings.length).toBe(1)
    })
```

The test passes but the react compiler or lint says:

> src/components/customcomponents/factory/ComponentFactory.test.jsx
> Line 7:9:  Promise should be returned to test its fulfillment or rejection  jest/valid-expect-in-promise

Ok, seems I need a catch, so:

```js
    test("should render text component", async () => {
        render(<TextComponent />)
        const headings = await screen.findAllByRole("heading").catch(expect(false))
        expect(headings.length).toBe(1)
    })
```

The test passes again, but I've got a new compiler error:

> src/components/customcomponents/TextComponent.test.jsx
> Line 8:32:  `findAllByRole` must have `await` operator  testing-library/await-async-query

Ok, so let's try with try...catch:

```js
    test("should render text component", async () => {
        render(<TextComponent />)
        try {
            const headings = await screen.findAllByRole("heading")
            expect(headings.length).toBe(1)
        } catch (err) {
            expect(err).toBeTruthy()
        }
    })
```

The test passes... but I've got a new error!:

> src/components/customcomponents/TextComponent.test.jsx
> Line 12:13:  Avoid calling `expect` conditionally`  jest/no-conditional-expect

So... What is the solution for this? What is the right code?

Thank you all!

Comment: Why is this test asynchronous?  My first inclination is to remove the async / await keywords.

Comment: This is linter and not compiler error, so you're busy with pleasing ESLint. The first snippet is totally ok, any rules that contradict it should be disabled because they are incompatible with it. Other snippets went wrong.

Comment: @GlenCarpenter screen.findAllByRole("heading") returns a promise.

Comment: @EstusFlask You're right, I think the problem is in ESLint.

Answer (score 0):

As some people commented, I think it's a ESLint problem, there's no problem with the code but i've got some code that *works* and ESLint *likes*:

```js
    test("should render text component", async () => {
        render(<TitleComponent />)
        let headingLength = 0;
        try {
            const headings = await screen.findAllByRole("heading")
            headingLength = headings.length
        } catch (err) { }
        expect(headingLength).toBe(1)
    })
```

The above code works, pass and doesn't get problems with ESLint. The drawback is that I hate `let`.